# Update items in adapter when other item clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer, android-arrayadapter

I am in stuck with pretty easy thing.

I have an activity with Fragment which includes RecyclerView and custom adapter with items.
This activity is about radio stations.

So in my adapter I have several items with Play-Stop button. When I click on the button there is "play" symbol. One more click on those button - there will be "stop" button. This logic works.

BUT if I will click on other item, on other Play-Stop button, all previously clicked items will save different states, so I want to change state for previous clicked item - only current clicked item with current position can have different Play-Stop button. **How can I get it?**

I have tried some `notify...()` methods but without result that I want. **I think I am trying notify adapter in the wrong places.**

```
            holder.LLPLayStop.setOnClickListener(v->{
                if (isPlay[0] == false) {
                    isPlay[0] = true;
                    try {
                        if (mp != null) {
                            mp.stop();
                            mp.release();
                        }
                        mp = new MediaPlayer();
                        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        mp.setDataSource("http://cast.radiogroup.com.ua:8000/avtoradio");
                        mp.prepareAsync();
    //                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                        holder.PBLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.list_item_play_stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mp.start();
                                holder.PBLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.list_item_play_stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.list_item_play_stop.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.radio_stop));
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "prepare() failed");
                    }
                } else {
                    isPlay[0] = false;
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                    mp = null;
//                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    holder.list_item_play_stop.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.radio_play));
                }
//                notifyItemChanged(position);
            });
```

Comment: isPlay[0] value coming from where?@danyapd

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit more `BUT if I will click on other item, on other Play-Stop button, all previously clicked items will save different states, so I want to change state for previous clicked item - only current clicked item with current position can have different Play-Stop button.`

Secondly since RecyclerView recycles the item it is possible your states are getting mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to keep playing index and check each time on click, for all rows. so you need variable to keep clicked row, like this:

in your adapter:

```
private Integer selectedPos = -1;
```

in `onClick` of play/stop button:

```
{
   selectedPos = position;
   notifyDataSetChanged(); // notify list , then each row can handle it's state base on selectedPos
}
```

and finally check playing row in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
 if(selectedPos == position){ // position is the current row position
     //this row is selected for playing...
     //do appropriate works
 } else{
     //this row is not select for play so change button style to normal
 }
```

Comment: was not so easy like I thought, BUT finally it works perfect, thanks.

for other people: I was need to take outside of my click listener `if(selectedPos == position){` logic and wrap it in my `if(isPlay[position])` logic